# How can I let each input show its number?

Tags: input

The problem I'm facing is that I want to know number of one input. For example, In`[1]:= (...)` then I know this is first input, but I found only the first input in a cell will show its number, then I wonder if there is some solution that can show all the number of input not only the first one in a cell.

Comment: As a hint, fwiw, I know that the input line number is managed by the front end through the `CellLabel` option. I don't know a way to do what you want, and I don't know whether it is possible or not. (You can inspect the input cell with the menu command Cell > Show Expression.)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the question. What do you mean by "only the first input in a cell will show its number"? What do you mean by "show all the number of input not only the first one in a cell"?

Comment: An example would help. But if you are putting several assignments in a cell, together they constitute one input. If you wish each assignment to be a separate input, then put each in a separate cell.